# numeric loop in volt

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

I have read the volt documentation in phalcon page and i cant find any example for this...

You can make easy loops in objects, for example, in php:

```
foreach($pages as $page){
    echo $page->title;
}
```

in volts would be ...

```
{% for page in pages %}
    {{ page.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

My question is, how i can make a normal numerical loop in volt? For example:

```
for($n=1;$n<10;$n++){
    echo $n;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This will count from 1 to 10

```
{% for i in 1..10 %}
    {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```